# Replace the max value for each column to 0 in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-manipulation

For example, I have a data set of this:

```
data = {
    "A": [1, 2, 3],
    "B": [3, 5, 1],
    "C": [9, 0, 1]
}

data_df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

```
data_df
   A  B   C
0  1  3   9
1  2  5   0
2  3  1   1
```

I want to replace the max value for each columns to 0. My desired output is:

```
   A  B   C
0  1  3   0
1  2  0   0
2  0  1   1
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: For whoever voted this down, you can leave me comment and let me know if I can improve the description of the question.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can interate through columns, get the max value and replace row with max value:

```py
for col in data_df.columns:
    data_df[col] = data_df[col].apply(lambda x: 0 if x==data_df.max()[col] else x)
```

Answer (score 1):

This works if your max value is unique.

Just be aware that `idxmax()` returns the first index of the maximum value. If the values occurs more often this won't work.

```
for col in df.columns:
    df.loc[df.idxmax()[col], col] = 0
```